# how to make an additional request and get data from it

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to parse data from the site. After parsing, data must be saved to disk. I am using scrapy. When working, I need to get data from another page. How can I do that?

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "my_spyder"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.example.com/title/1',
        'https://www.example.com/title/2',
        'https://www.example.com/title/3',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
       item = MyItem()
       main_page_selector = Selector(response)
       ...
       tagline_url = os.path.join(response.url, 'taglines')
       request = Request(url=tagline_url, callback=get_tags)   
       item['tags'] = yield request
       ...
       yield item

    def get_tags(self, response):
        tagline_selector = Selector(response)
        taglines = []
        for tag in tagline_selector.xpath('//div[@class="soda even"))]/text()').getall():
            taglines.append(tag.strip())

        return taglines
```

how to write in the 'item' field 'tags' received during the function 'get_tags'?
these requests are executed asynchronously.

Comment: Firstly, is `callback=get_taglines` meant to be `callback=get_tags`? 

Have you had a look at scrapy's metadata support, allowing you to pass a key-value object around, specifically the `cb_kwargs` function. You can (apparently) yield a dictionary from your callback. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

I have used something like this but without a callback to accumulate info over several page visits.

Answer (score 1):

```
request = Request(url=tagline_url, callback=get_tags)
request.meta["item"] = item
yield request
```

Above code on parse method

```
item = response.meta["item"]
#...
item["tags"] = taglines
yield item
```

The second code in the get_tags method